# Javascript regex to find a particular string which could be broken across multiple lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex which gets a particular substring from a string. However, the substring could be broken across multiple lines.

I've tried using the multiline flag, like this:

`"foo\nbar".match(/foobar/m)`

But that returns `null`.

I've also seen a number of posts suggesting I use `[\S\s]`. However, as far as I can tell, this only works if you know where the break line will be, like this:

`'foo\nbar'.match(/foo[\S\s]bar/m)`

Is there a way to find all instaces of `foobar` in a string when the line break could anywhere in the string?

Comment: `Is there a way to find all instances of foobar in a string when the line break could anywhere in the string?` Remove all line-breaks from subject before comparing with your regex

Comment: Use `*?` quantifier: `/foo[\S\s]*?bar/`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that only works if you know where the line break is though. So doesn't work for `'foob\nar'.match(/foo[\S\s]*?bar/)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it would only work if you know where the string is split by \n and it seems it's not sure - it can be `fo\nobar`

Comment: Ok, `var pattern = s.split("").join("\\s*"); var rx = RegExp(pattern); console.log(rx.test(s))`. If there can be chars other than whitespace, use `.*?` instead of `\\s*`.

Comment: Thanks all. @WiktorStribiżew I ended up using anubhava's approach so have accepted that as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find all instances of foobar in a string when the line break could anywhere in the string?

Remove all line-breaks from subject before comparing with your regex.

See this simple demo:

```js
const arr = ["foo\nbar", "\nfoobar", "fo\nobar", "foobar\n", "foobar"];

const val = 'foobar';

arr.forEach(function(el) {
   console.log(el.replace(/\n/, '') == val)
});
```